# nginx fails to load ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have to add ssl (https) for a website, I was given a SSL.CSR and a SSL.KEY file.  I 'dos2unix'ed them (because they have trailing ^M) and copied them to the server(CSR -> mywebsite.crt, KEY -> mywebsite.key).  I did the following modification to nginx.conf:

```
@@ -60,8 +60,13 @@
        }

     server {
-       listen       80;
+       listen       443;
         server_name  ...;
+       ssl                 on;
+       ssl_certificate     mywebsite.crt;
+       ssl_certificate_key mywebsite.key;
+       ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
+       ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        # Set the max size for file uploads to 500Mb

        client_max_body_size 500M;
```

Error happens when I restart nginx:

```
nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/nginx/mywebsite.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
```

I figure it's because the first line of mywebsite.crt file contains 'REQUEST', so I remove 'REQUEST' from the first and last of the lines, and restart nginx again, and hit another error:

```
nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/nginx/mywebsite.crt") failed (SSL: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:Field=algorithm, Type=X509_ALGOR error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:Field=signature, Type=X509_CINF error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:Field=cert_info, Type=X509 error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib)
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can get free Class 1 Server certificates from [StartCom](https://www.startcom.org/). Submit the CSR, and get a CRT back (signed certificate). Convert the CRT to PEM, and concatenate StartCom's [Class 1 Server Intermediate](https://www.startssl.com/certs/) certificate to the file with the PEM encoded certificate you just converted. And as Mark said, throw away that key.

Comment: By the way, `openssl req -in mycsr.csr -noout -text` prints the CSR. Your CSR is malformed - since it has a Common Name (CN), the same host name needs to be listed as a Subject Alt Name (SAN). CN is deprecated, and you should just list *.example.net as a SAN (and omit the CN). See the Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates from the CA/Browser forums.

Comment: @noloader Thanks for your answer!  Actually I used the wrong file, I  was given a CertB64.cer file which is accepted by nginx. Now I have another two problems: 1) Firefox complains the certificate has no 'issuer chain' 2) all the pics (hosted on asset.bbb.aaa.mywebsite.com) can't be loaded because Chrome and IE complain the certificate (issued for \*.aaa.mywebsite.com) is not for asset.bbb.aaa.mywebsite.com, pics can only be opened if I manually open pic URL and confirm security exception.  I guess I need to get another certificate issued for *.*.aaa.mywebsite.com with issuer chain included?

Comment: I hit this problem on macOS. By mistake I exported the `Public Key` of each Certificate in my Chain instead of the Certificate files.  Once I exported the Cert files (as PEM files) and chained them together, it all worked.

Comment: See https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/126

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should never share your private key. You should consider the key you posted here compromised and generate a new key and signing request.

You have a certificate request and not an actual signed certificate. You provide the request ('CSR') to the signing party. They use that request to create a signed certificate ('CRT') which they then make available to you. The key is never disclosed to anyone.

Comment: And how do I get a CSR? I was given a CRT and a KEY file.

Comment: @PaulKenjora CSR can be generated by self using openssl

Answer (score 29):

FYI, you can validate the keys just calling:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in your.crt
openssl rsa -noout -text -in your.key
```

In my case this error proved rather subtle: the BEGIN block started with **4 dashes, not 5**. `----` vs `-----`. Sadly the validation tool error messages aren't very specific.

Comment: In my case the newlines after BEGIN and before END dashed lines were lost and I had to add them back.

Comment: Thank you @joseph-lust, I was able to pin point the issue using this.
I had generated my .crt file from .pem using openssl and openssl wasn't able to validate it.

Comment: In my case i got extra spaces in beginning of each line while copy-paste.

Comment: in my case, the files were sent to me via slack which converted ----- into ——

Answer (score 16):

I came across this issue while searching online for SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
I got this error after running:

```
    nginx -t
```

The problem I had was that cert.pem and cert.key was missing

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: `nginx -t` let me know that the format of the .crt I was working with wasn't correct. I double checked and during import (I was installing the certificate using an external service) the .crt file was getting mangled. Thanks man.

Comment: same case here .

Answer (score 9):

The steps on [the NGINX site](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) for combining your public certificate with an intermediate certificate use `cat` to combine the two files.  But if your public cert file does not end in a new line, the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line of the intermediate cert will be appended to the end of the `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` line of the public certificate, leading to an invalid chained certificate file.  Manually separating these two lines can correct the issue.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, was pulling my hair for half an hour :)

Comment: all it was for me was a typo in the initial cert generation. i just had to redo the cert.

Comment: For me the command `cat` to concatenate the two certificates was somehow creating repetitive content in the merged `.crt` file. So I manually concatenated the two certificates to create the `.crt` file and then Nginx stopped complaining.

Answer (score 5):

I configured the certificates wrongly in `gitlab.rb` file.
A simple error took long to realize.

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/self-ssl.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/self-ssl.key"
```

**Instead of**

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/self-ssl.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/self-ssl.key"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the reason was that the lines `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` of one certificate and `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` of another one happened to be on the same line, so basically:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

this happened after I merged a few `crt` files in a bundle through command line and between files there was no newline added, which corrupted the whole `crt` file.

fixed it by splitting the line

Answer (score 0):

Because I was working in a different structure, I had copied the `.crt` and `.key` files from one place to another and then faced the same problem.

Actually, the problem is very simple. Had to set permissions again after copying.

In short, I solved the problem by changing the owner of the file.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/.key/file
```

(development only)